Prove that $\frac{(\sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i a_i)^2}{\sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i b_i} \geq \min_{i} \frac{a_i^2}{b_i}$
Let $\sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i = 1$ and $a_i, b_i \in (0,1]$ be two sequences. Does the inequality $$\frac{(\sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i a_i)^2}{\sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i b_i} \geq \min_{i} \frac{a_i^2}{b_i}$$ hold true in general? I tried solving this using induction but failed. I have see similar inequalities. For example $\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i}{\sum_{i = 1}^n b_i} \geq \min_{i} \frac{a_i}{b_i}$ but none that satisfies my need.
I do see that I could rewrite the problem as
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E}[a]^2}{\mathbb{E}[b]} \geq \min_{\omega} \frac{a^2(\omega)}{b(\omega)}
$$
if I view $a_i$ and $b_i$ as random variables on a common discrete probability space but this did not help me either.

Where did you learn about this inequality? Maybe that has certain hints as to how it can be proved?

Counter example:
Take $a_i^2 = t\cdot b_i$ for all $i \ge 1$ with $t>0$. The inequality is equivalent to
$$\frac{(\sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i \sqrt{tb_i})^2}{\sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i b_i} \geq t\iff \sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i \sqrt{b_i} \color{red}{\ge} \sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i b_i} $$
However, by applying the Jensen's inequality to the concave function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, we have:
$$\sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i \sqrt{b_i} \color{red}{\le} \sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i b_i}$$

Thank you very much for your answer. I remember that I attacked the problem from a different angle and this was a a counterexample. I had just hoped that this was a somewhat different formulation which where this would not be a counterexample.
